# how to disable security.info and security.debug in monolog symfony2 logging

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I constantly am seeing a bunch of the following log:

```
[2015-02-15 09:08:16] request.INFO: Matched route "AppMainBundle_daftar_toko_province" (parameters: "_controller": "App\MainBundle\Controller\ZHomepageController::daftarTokoAction", "provinceName": "DKI JAKARTA", "_route": "AppMainBundle_daftar_toko_province") [] []
[2015-02-15 09:08:16] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2015-02-15 09:08:16] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

in my prod.log, how can I disable this and I just want to see the errors. Here is my monolog settings:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: file
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/items/
        file:
            type: stream
            level: debug
        doctrine:
            action_level: debug
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/doctrine_%kernel.environment%.log
            channels: doctrine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define which channels to be logged. Use something like this to ignore a specific channel:

```
        channels: ["!security"]
```

If you only want to ignore specific log levels you can use the 
level param or use a combination of both in a new handler.

Answer (score 1):

In symfony4(And maybe higher versions)
https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#switching-a-channel-to-a-different-handler

```yaml
File: \config\packages\dev\monolog.yaml

    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event", "!request", "!security"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console", "!request", "!security"]
```

In my config (WebServer) of symfony4.4 I had `channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]` for Console and `channels: ["!event"]` for Main