# Symfony 2.8 disable security/request.INFO logging

Tags: symfony

Symfony is logging two `INFO` level statements for *every* request in my application, inflating an apache log file very rapidly. We're not using Monolog (using an alternate solution), and I've disabled it by removing the bundle in the AppKernel.

```
[2016-06-23 12:11:04] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-06-23 12:11:06] request.INFO: Matched route "contact". {"route_parameters":{"_controller": ...
```

How can I disable this logging?

Comment: you mean apache log? not sf2 logs?

Comment: The notices end up in a general apache log, but symfony is emitting them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to disable security.info and security.debug in monolog symfony2 logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523211/how-to-disable-security-info-and-security-debug-in-monolog-symfony2-logging)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens because Monolog (which symfony will use itself even if you disable it in your app) [defaults to `std:error`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/673e275c00fe935f90d6996b5da2e41affe5df3e/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L229):

```
public function addRecord($level, $message, array $context = array())
{
    if (!$this->handlers) {
        $this->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stderr', static::DEBUG));
    }
```

Adding *any* handler in `app/config/config.yml` will make `addRecord` reject the unwanted info notice instead.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        syslog:
            type: syslog
            level: error
```