# event.DEBUG, doctrine.DEBUG, security.DEBUG make dev.log file hugely big

Tags: symfony, debugging, logging, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I run an app on Symfony2. Whenever I load a page or a controller, dev.log file get fill with thousands and thousands with these kind of lines :

```
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] request.INFO: Matched route "getVersion" (parameters: "domain": "BID", "id": "7694", "_controller": "Sii\StimasBundle\Controller\UpdateFolderController::getVersion", "_route": "getVersion") [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2017-10-12 15:26:09] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0
...thousands and thousands of the kind of same lines
```

Which make the file very very huge over time and it's very annoying.

Here is my config_dev.yml file :

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info
#        chromephp:
#            type:  chromephp
#            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```

What could be the problem and how to get rid of ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `config_dev`, section `monolog`, change `debug` logging level to some higher level, for example, `info`, or 'error'.

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        channels: ['!event']
```

You might also want to set up `fingers_crossed` to save debug messages, but only if error occurs, [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#handlers-that-modify-log-entries) is documentation.

Another way is to disable specific error logging channels.
Under `channels` add `['!event', '!doctrine', '!security']` to ignore specific channels: "event", "doctrine", "security" accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I just did that, but it only get rid of `event.DEBUG`. `doctrine.DEBUG`, `security.DEBUG` are still there !

Comment: @kabrice What level you are using now?

Comment: There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523211/how-to-disable-security-info-and-security-debug-in-monolog-symfony2-logging) which shows how to disable specific channels, and I like it more.

Comment: I use `level: debug`. On the other hand I'm afraid that if I disable those channels (security, events etc), I could miss some useful debug messages as all debug messages aren't useless.

Comment: @kabrice This way only fingers_crossed filter or periodic deletion will help.

Comment: Does it work on Symfony2.2 ? Because I just changed  `type:  stream` to `type:  fingers_crossed` and I get the error : `...Undefined index: handler in /var/www/myproject/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle...`

Comment: @kabrice if you don't want to study the documentation, just change `level: debug` to a higher level like `level: info`

Comment: I just changed `type: stream` to `type: fingers_crossed`  and `level: debug` to `level: info` and I got the same error above :(

Comment: The `channels: ['!event']` should be better publicised!

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the debug option enabled as it is and I will go with [File Rotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#how-to-rotate-your-log-files):

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            # max number of log files to keep
            # defaults to zero, which means infinite files
            max_files: 10
```

Is what I am using currently and does not bother me at all, that way I can keep the debug messages in case I needed and a fixed amount of files.

Or .... you can mix both solutions if you like.